# Sending an empty line to the php page

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following form where we have the possibility to add the necessary lines as follows:

```js
function addAgregado(){ 
    $("#riscos").append("<div>"+$("#riscoform").html()+"</div>"); 
} 

function inserir_agregado()
{   
    var IdAgreg = [];
    $("input[name='IdAgreg[]']").each(function() {IdAgreg.push(this.value)});
    
    var Parent = [];
    $("input[name='Parent[]']").each(function() {Parent.push(this.value)});
    
    var ParentNome = [];
    $("input[name='ParentNome[]']").each(function() {ParentNome.push(this.value)});
    
    var ParentIdade = [];
    $("input[name='ParentIdade[]']").each(function() {ParentIdade.push(this.value)});
    
    var dadosajax = {
        'contribuinte' : $("#contribuinte").val(),
        'IdAgreg[]' : IdAgreg,
        'Parent[]' : Parent,
        'ParentNome[]' : ParentNome,
        'ParentIdade[]' : ParentIdade
    };
    
    $.ajax({
        url: 'regagregado.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: dadosajax,
        error: function(){
          Swal.fire("Erro!", "Tente novamente. Caso persista o erro, contatar Administrador!", "error");
        },
        success: function(result)
        {         
        }
    });    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">
        
          <label for="educacao">Composição do Agregado Familiar (Parentesco, Nome e Idade) <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>

          <button type="button" class="hs-button primary large" onclick="addAgregado()" >Adicionar Familiar</button>
          
        </div>
         <div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field" id="riscos">
     
     </div>
     
     <div id="riscoform" hidden> 
<table class="campo" cellspacing="10"> 
<tr>
<td style="display: none;">
    <div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">
        
        <label for="IdAgreg">Id </label>

        <input name="IdAgreg[]" type="text" >
        
    </div>

</td> 
<td>
    <div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">
        
        <label for="Parent">Parentesco </label>

        <input name="Parent[]" required="required" type="text" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Campo obrigatório" >
        <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
            <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
        </span>
    </div>

</td> 
<td> 
    <div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">
        
        <label for="ParentNome">Nome </label>

        <input name="ParentNome[]" required="required" type="text" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Campo obrigatório" >
        <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
            <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
        </span>
    </div> 
</td> 
<td>
    <div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">
        
        <label for="ParentIdade">Idade </label>

        <input name="ParentIdade[]" required="required" type="text" placeholder="" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Campo obrigatório" >
        <span class="error1" style="display: none;">
            <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
        </span>
    </div> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 

</div>

<input class="hs-button primary large action-button visivel" type="button" onclick="inserir_agregado();" value="Submeter">
```

All the code is working and being inserted in the database.
But I have a problem, whenever I insert it into the database, always insert a blank line. Example when filling two lines:

> contribuinte: xxxxxxxxx IdAgreg[]:  IdAgreg[]:  IdAgreg[]:  Parent[]:
> Pai Parent[]: Mae Parent[]:  ParentNome[]: Bruno ParentNome[]: Monica
> ParentNome[]:  ParentIdade[]: 37 ParentIdade[]: 33 ParentIdade[]:

In this example I only filled in two lines, but when sending to the page regagregado.php sends an empty line. What is the reason?

Comment: ```this.value```  in the ```each function``` should be ```this.val()``` because ```this``` is a jquery object

Comment: @ikhvjs Returns this error Uncaught TypeError: this.val is not a function

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: @ikhvjs I have already tested your question and in my code and just insert the first line as I commented below in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change your `.each()` function and pass `$(this).val()` instead.

and Console.log the result.

**Example below.**

```js
function addAgregado() {
  $("#riscos").append("<div>" + $("#riscoform").html() + "</div>");
}

function inserir_agregado() {
  var IdAgreg = [];
  $("input[name='IdAgreg[]']").each(function () {
    IdAgreg.push($(this).val());
  });

  var Parent = [];
  $("input[name='Parent[]']").each(function () {
    Parent.push($(this).val());
  });

  var ParentNome = [];
  $("input[name='ParentNome[]']").each(function () {
    ParentNome.push($(this).val());
  });

  var ParentIdade = [];
  $("input[name='ParentIdade[]']").each(function () {
    ParentIdade.push($(this).val());
  });

  var dadosajax = {
    contribuinte: $("#contribuinte").val(),
    "IdAgreg[]": IdAgreg,
    "Parent[]": Parent,
    "ParentNome[]": ParentNome,
    "ParentIdade[]": ParentIdade,
  };

  console.log(dadosajax);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">
  <label for="educacao"
    >Composição do Agregado Familiar (Parentesco, Nome e Idade)
    <span style="color: red">*</span></label
  >

  <button type="button" class="hs-button primary large" onclick="addAgregado()">
    Adicionar Familiar
  </button>
</div>
<div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field" id="riscos"></div>

<div id="riscoform">
  <table class="campo" cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">
          <label for="IdAgreg">Id </label>
          <input name="IdAgreg[]" type="text" />
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">
          <label for="Parent">Parentesco </label>
          <input
            name="Parent[]"
            required="required"
            type="text"
            placeholder=""
            data-rule-required="true"
            data-msg-required="Campo obrigatório"
          />
          <span class="error1" style="display: none">
            <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">
          <label for="ParentNome">Nome </label>
          <input
            name="ParentNome[]"
            required="required"
            type="text"
            placeholder=""
            data-rule-required="true"
            data-msg-required="Campo obrigatório"
          />
          <span class="error1" style="display: none">
            <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="hs_firstname field hs-form-field">
          <label for="ParentIdade">Idade </label>

          <input
            name="ParentIdade[]"
            required="required"
            type="text"
            placeholder=""
            data-rule-required="true"
            data-msg-required="Campo obrigatório"
          />
          <span class="error1" style="display: none">
            <i class="error-log fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<input
  class="hs-button primary large action-button visivel"
  type="button"
  onclick="inserir_agregado();"
  value="Submeter"
/>
```

Comment: But this way, it only takes the value of the first line, it does not send data from the other lines that I add

Comment: I updated my answer. It should work as you want now. The problem is you should pass ```$(this).val()``` in your each function.

Comment: If you test the updated answer, you will again have the problem I asked in the question, insert a blank line

Comment: I notice you hide the first form and that's why you have a blank line item in all the array. I remove all the hidden styles and there is no empty line.